# SQL - Problem involving join , count and max

Tags: mysql

I have a data which has manager id, emp id and emp weekoff. For every 10 employees there is a manager. I have to assign the week off of the manager based on the maximum common weekoff of emp. For example.

```
Manager ID | Emp id | Emp off 1 | Emp off 2 
1 | a | fri | sat
1 | b | sat| sun
1 | c | sun| mon 
2 | d | mon | tue
2 | e | wed| thu
1 | f | wed| thu
2 | g | mon| tue
```

The output should be

```
Manger id|Manger off 1| Manager off 2 |No of emp having that week off 1|No of emp having that week off 2
1|sat | sun | 2 | 2
2 |mon| tue | 2 |2
```

I have wrote a query for this :

```
select wo1.`Manager id`, wo1.`emp off 1` as `Manger off 1` ,wo2.`emp off 2` as `Manger off 2`,count(  wo1.`emp off 2`) as 'No of emp having that week off 1',  count(  wo2.`emp off 2`) as No of emp having that week off 2` 
from ( select `Manager id`,`emp off 1`,count(`emp off 1`) from `table_name`  group by  manager,`week off 1` order by  count(`emp off 1`) desc) as wo1 ,
from ( select `Manager id`,`emp off 2`,count(`emp off 2`) from `table_name`  group by  manager,`week off 2` order by  count(`emp off 2`) desc) as wo2 
where wo1.`Manager id`=wo2.`Manager id`  group by `Manager id`;
```

I got the week off correct from the above query, but the count is not working. I have tried running the query for individual week off and it works but when I combine the 2 queries, it doesnt.

```
select `emp off 1`,count(`emp off 1`) from table_name WHERE 'manager id='1 group by  `emp off 1` order by  count(`emp off 1`) desc limit 1 ;
```

Comment: Where does agent come from

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Can you please format your Question to make it a little more easy to read? Your queries are on very long lines and you seem to have plain text formatted as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky, since you want to apply a limit within a group by without having a table structure for a proper group by. First I removed all the spaces in your table name and row names. Then I added a few extra rows to your table, that I called `empOff`, which I believe you call `table_name`:

```
(1, 'h', 'wed', 'fri'), -- extra
(1, 'i', 'mon', 'sun'), -- extra
```

#### Normalizing

I created a table for better handling of a group by, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE empOffNorm AS
SELECT ManagerID, EmpID, EmpOff1 AS empOffDay
  FROM empOff
UNION
SELECT ManagerID, EmpID, EmpOff2 AS empOffDay
  FROM empOff;
```

..it contains a row for every day an employee has a day off:

```
ManagerID | EmpID | empOffDay
----------|-------|----------
1         | a     | fri
1         | a     | sat
1         | b     | sat
1         | b     | sun
1         | c     | sun
1         | c     | mon
...
```

#### Grouping

Now it's possible to group the data and count the occurence of each day for the `ManagerID`s:

```
SELECT ManagerID, EmpOffDay, count(1) AS cnt
  FROM empOffNorm
 GROUP BY ManagerID, EmpOffDay
 ORDER BY ManagerID, cnt DESC
```

..and the data presents with count:

```
ManagerID | EmpOffDay | cnt
----------|-----------|----
1         | sun       | 3   <-- this
1         | fri       | 2   <-- this
1         | sat       | 2
1         | wed       | 2
1         | mon       | 2
1         | thu       | 1
2         | mon       | 2   <-- this
2         | tue       | 2   <-- this
2         | wed       | 1
2         | thu       | 1
```

..I've marked the rows you want to extract. It's easy to get them if a specific `ManagerID` is provided:

```
SELECT ManagerID, EmpOffDay, count(1) AS cnt
  FROM empOffNorm
 WHERE ManagerID = 1
 GROUP BY ManagerID, EmpOffDay
 ORDER BY cnt DESC, ManagerID
 LIMIT 2

ManagerID | EmpOffDay | cnt
----------|-----------|----
1         | sun       | 3
1         | fri       | 2
```

But not so easy for get them for all `ManagerID`'s. To make it easier to work with I created another table based on the grouped data, and I called the table `grouped`:

```
CREATE TABLE grouped AS
SELECT ManagerID, EmpOffDay, count(1) AS cnt
  FROM empOffNorm
 GROUP BY ManagerID, EmpOffDay
 ORDER BY ManagerID, cnt DESC
```

#### Using rownumbers

To only get rows based on the first two occurences for every `ManagerID` on the `grouped` table, I used three variables based on [How to Number Rows in MySQL](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/):

- `@rownum` just increments on every row.
- `@manrownum` also increments on every row, but it resets when it sees a new `ManagerID`.
- `@ManId` is s dummy variable that is set on every row. It's needed for the `@manrownum` variable.

Using them in on the `grouped` table:

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS RowNo,
       @manrownum := IF(@ManId = ManagerID, @manrownum + 1, 1) AS ManId_RowNo,
       @ManId := ManagerID AS Dummy_ManId,
       ManagerID,
       EmpOffDay,
       cnt
  FROM grouped
  JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0, @manrownum:=0, @ManId:='') variables;

RowNo | ManId_RowNo | Dummy_ManId | ManagerID | EmpOffDay | cnt
------|-------------|-------------|-----------|-----------|---- 
1     | 1           | 1           | 1         | sun       | 3
2     | 2           | 1           | 1         | fri       | 2
3     | 3           | 1           | 1         | sat       | 2
4     | 4           | 1           | 1         | wed       | 2
5     | 5           | 1           | 1         | mon       | 2
6     | 6           | 1           | 1         | thu       | 1
7     | 1           | 2           | 2         | mon       | 2   <-- ManId_RowNo restarted
8     | 2           | 2           | 2         | tue       | 2
9     | 3           | 2           | 2         | wed       | 1
10    | 4           | 2           | 2         | thu       | 1
```

..and now it's possible to fetch just the first two rows for each manager:

```
SELECT ManagerID, EmpOffDay, cnt
  FROM (
        SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS RowNo,
               @manrownum := IF(@ManId = ManagerID, @manrownum + 1, 1) AS ManId_RowNo,
               @ManId := ManagerID AS Dummy_ManId,
               ManagerID,
               EmpOffDay,
               cnt
          FROM grouped
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0, @manrownum:=0, @ManId:='') variables
       ) AS rownumbered 
WHERE ManId_RowNo < 3; -- here the limit 2 is applied for every ManangerId

ManagerID | EmpOffDay | cnt
----------|-----------|----
1         | sun       | 3
1         | fri       | 2
2         | mon       | 2
2         | tue       | 2
```

#### Not using any of the created tables

Inserting all the original queries then gives you:

```
SELECT ManagerID, EmpOffDay, cnt
  FROM (
        SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS RowNo,
               @manrownum := if(@ManId = ManagerID, @manrownum + 1, 1) AS ManId_RowNo,
               @ManId := ManagerID AS Dummy_ManId,
               ManagerID,
               EmpOffDay,
               cnt
          FROM (
                SELECT ManagerID, EmpOffDay, count(1) AS cnt
                  FROM (SELECT ManagerID, EmpID, EmpOff1 AS empOffDay
                         FROM empOff
                        UNION
                       SELECT ManagerID, EmpID, EmpOff2 AS empOffDay
                         FROM empOff) AS empOffDayNorm
                 GROUP BY ManagerID, EmpOffDay
                 ORDER BY ManagerID, cnt DESC
               ) AS grouped
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0, @manrownum:=0, @ManId:='') variables
       ) AS normed_grouped_sorted_rownumbed
 WHERE ManId_RowNo < 3;
```

#### Denormalizing results

To get the result in the format you wanted, I created another table as the query above:

```
CREATE TABLE denorm AS ...
```

..and then joined it with itself:

```
SELECT denorm1.ManagerID, denorm1.EmpOffDay, denorm2.EmpOffDay, denorm1.cnt, denorm2.cnt
  FROM denorm denorm1
  JOIN denorm denorm2 ON denorm1.ManagerID = denorm2.ManagerID
                     AND denorm1.EmpOffDay < denorm2.EmpOffDay
```

..to get your desired result:

```
ManagerID | EmpOffDay | EmpOffDay | cnt | cnt
----------|-----------|-----------|-----|----
1         | fri       | sun       | 2   | 3
2         | mon       | tue       | 2   | 2
```

Of course you can just insert the bigger query instead of using the `denorm` table:

```
SELECT denorm1.ManagerID, denorm1.EmpOffDay, denorm2.EmpOffDay, denorm1.cnt, denorm2.cnt
  FROM (SELECT ManagerID, EmpOffDay, cnt
          FROM (
                SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS RowNo,
                       @manrownum := if(@ManId = ManagerID, @manrownum + 1, 1) AS ManId_RowNo,
                       @ManId := ManagerID AS Dummy_ManId,
                       ManagerID,
                       EmpOffDay,
                       cnt
                  FROM (
                        SELECT ManagerID, EmpOffDay, count(1) AS cnt
                          FROM (SELECT ManagerID, EmpID, EmpOff1 AS empOffDay
                                 FROM empOff
                                UNION
                               SELECT ManagerID, EmpID, EmpOff2 AS empOffDay
                                 FROM empOff) AS empOffDayNorm
                         GROUP BY ManagerID, EmpOffDay
                         ORDER BY ManagerID, cnt DESC
                       ) AS grouped
                  JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0, @manrownum:=0, @ManId:='') variables
               ) AS normed_grouped_sorted_rownumbed
         WHERE ManId_RowNo < 3) AS denorm1
  JOIN (SELECT ManagerID, EmpOffDay, cnt
          FROM (
                SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS RowNo,
                       @manrownum := if(@ManId = ManagerID, @manrownum + 1, 1) AS ManId_RowNo,
                       @ManId := ManagerID AS Dummy_ManId,
                       ManagerID,
                       EmpOffDay,
                       cnt
                  FROM (
                        SELECT ManagerID, EmpOffDay, count(1) AS cnt
                          FROM (SELECT ManagerID, EmpID, EmpOff1 AS empOffDay
                                 FROM empOff
                                UNION
                               SELECT ManagerID, EmpID, EmpOff2 AS empOffDay
                                 FROM empOff) AS empOffDayNorm
                         GROUP BY ManagerID, EmpOffDay
                         ORDER BY ManagerID, cnt DESC
                       ) AS grouped
                  JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0, @manrownum:=0, @ManId:='') variables
               ) AS normed_grouped_sorted_rownumbed
         WHERE ManId_RowNo < 3) AS denorm2 
    ON denorm1.ManagerID = denorm2.ManagerID
   AND denorm1.EmpOffDay < denorm2.EmpOffDay
```

---

Find it all at [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=448ec49a5d1de046a99f8033429b9085)

---

I've played with it a little more. There is a solution that doesn't require any variables. It uses the 
`empOffNorm` table from "Normalizing", and for any given `ManagerID` it **only** fetches the two wanted rows as described in "Grouping" above.

That query is then wrapped into a subselect so only those two records can ever be fetched.

When running the query for all managers, a check for `EXISTS` is made against the wrapped subselect, ensuring `EXISTS` only return true on those records:

```
SELECT ManagerID, EmpOffDay, count(1) AS cnt
  FROM empOffNorm eon
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM (SELECT ManagerID, EmpOffDay, count(1) AS cnt
                        FROM empOffNorm wrapped
                       WHERE wrapped.ManagerID = eon.ManagerID -- this particular id
                       GROUP BY ManagerID, EmpOffDay
                       ORDER BY cnt DESC, ManagerId
                       LIMIT 2
                     ) AS limited -- always only 2 rows
               WHERE limited.ManagerID = eon.ManagerID
                 AND limited.EmpOffDay = eon.EmpOffDay
              )
 GROUP BY ManagerID, EmpOffDay
 ORDER BY cnt DESC, ManagerID
```

It doesn't denormalize the result though, so it returns two rows for each manager.